Power App - Filtering gallery with drop down values
Filter('Application Details',
'Application Status'= \[@'Application Status'\].Active,
StartsWith('App #',AppNum.Text),
Borrower = Customer.Selected.Value,
'Status (cr6b8_status)' = Status.Selected.Value,
'APP Start Date' = StartDate.Selected.Value,
'Last Status Change' = StatusDate.Selected.Value,
'Sales Person (AEL)' = SalesPerson.Selected.Value
)

I have 5 drop downs that grab their items like the following from a Dataverse Table: Distinct('Application Details', 'Status (cr6b8_status)'). I'm wanting to filter a gallery from the same table 'Application Details'.
This seems to work, but all of the filters need to be exactly the same as the item in the gallery. I want to be able to use some as well as all filters. For example, just filtering specific statuses.
Any suggestions or ideas on the implementation of this? Or anything I could change?
